# Sorted extraction

Tags: probability

I have numbered balls from $1$ to $N$ in an urn and take out $n$ balls, one at a time, putting it back each time. I want to calculate the probability of getting a strictly growing sequence. I thought about doing it with success cases over total cases.

If I'm not mistaken, total cases would be $N^n$ and success cases would be $\frac{\binom{N}{n}}{n!}$. I think the total cases are like this since it would be that I can choose between $N$ balls in $n$ oportunities, and the success cases I thought it like I have to choose $n$ different numbers between the $N$ possibilities and since it has to be sorted growing, I have to remove the repeats, so I divide by $n!$

The thing I'm insecure about this is that I've also programmed this and the result is giving me more like $\frac{\binom{N}{n}}{N^n}$ which I think it should be wrong, but watching results I can't find any bug, so I'm not sure if I have a bug or I'm thinking it incorrectly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things going on.  The first is that you have to draw $n$ distinct balls, and the second is that they have to come in increasing order.  Given that the balls are distinct, the probability that they come in increasing order is $\frac1{n!}$.

Now there are $n!\binom{N}{n}$ ways to draw $n$ distinct balls, and $N^n$ equally likely ways to draw the balls, so the probability is $$\frac{\binom{N}{n}}{N^n}$$ as your simulations confirm.